# Rails count has_many relations and group by another field in a child model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, count, group-by, has-many

Consider this setup

```
class Device
  has_many :job_transactions
end

class JobTransaction
  belongs_to :device
  # relevant attributes
  # sequential_id ( each transaction gets a sequential if using Sequenced Gem)
  # station - work station ( let say a total of 10) 
  # station is an enum


end
```

Each Job has multiple  transactions and after each transaction is done a job, is moved from one station to another ( they can be moved multiple time to different or even same transaction)

I want to figure out how many jobs (units) are there at each station at the moment  using highest sequential id.

so the result should be

```
{
"Station 1" => 500,
"Station 2" => 123,
etc..
}
```

My problem is making sure that I only count latest transaction for each device, and not the 1 or some other. As I need to figure out how many devices are at each station currently.

**UPDATE:**

Essentially I want to optimize this dirty piece of code:

```
 has_one :latest_transaction, -> { order sequential_id: :desc }, 
          class_name: 'JobTransaction', 
          foreign_key: 'job_id'


h = Device.joins(:job_transactions).
            map{|l| l.latest_transaction.station}.
            reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |a, b| a[b] += 1; a };
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a faster solution, but I'm still looking for a SQL solution

```
JobTransaction.select('job_id, station, sequential_id').
               group_by(&:job_id).
               reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |a, b| a[b.last.last.station] += 1; a }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do:

```
#app/models/device.rb
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :job_transactions
   scope :count_transactions, -> { joins(:job_transacations).group(:job_id).count }
end
```

I don't get this requirement:

> I only count latest transaction for each device

Perhaps if you clarify, we can get something worked out?

Comment: Hi. Each device has several job_transactions : 1, 3, 7, etc.  when I group by station - I only want to group using the latest (last, with highest  sequential_id) transactions. By default mysql will grab the first record that qualifies not the the last  (this is what your suggestion would do as well )- so when I group - I keep getting only the the station at the first transaction, not the last ( most recent, current if you will)  - see my Update 2 - essentially trying to figure out how to implement that group_by& reduce in SQL